# Combining two columns to create a datetime object

Tags: python, pandas, string, text-mining

I would need to create a datetime by combining two columns in a dataframe. 
My original dataset has these columns:

```
Date                Time
05/29/2020         00:12
05/29/2020         00:32
05/28/2020         00.59
```

I would like to create a new column which combines `Date + Time`, i.e. which creates a datetime object:

```
Date_time
05/22/2020 00:12
05/22/2020 00:32
05/28/2020 00:59
```

I used

```
df['Time'] = df['Time'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

but the output gave me today's date plus values from column `Time 2020-05-29 00:22:00`.
How could I get the right date by using the columns Date and Time above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
df['Date_time']=pd.to_datetime(df.Date+ ' '+df.Time, format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
```